# Stretch the slanted line to an extreme

Tags: java, javafx

Assuming that there is a line formed (A)=x1,y1 and (B)=x2,y2
This line is drawn on the screen, now I need this line to reach the ends of the screen.

Is there any formula that makes it possible to continue the line while maintaining the angle of inclination?

I know that JavaFX has a lot of resources, I accept suggestions

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


  

public class LineContinue extends Application {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(0);
        line.setStartY(150);
        
        line.setEndX(170);
        line.setEndY(50);
        
        line.setLayoutX(10);
        line.setLayoutY(10);
        
            
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(line);
        
        line.setLayoutX(100);
        line.setLayoutY(200);
        
        
        Button b = new Button("Extreme Line");
        b.setOnAction( (e) -> {
             
             // formula continue line until extreme
             
        
        });
        
        
        bp.setCenter(pane);
        bp.setBottom(b);
  
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bp));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Extreme Line");
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }    
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a maths question.

You need to find the point of intersection of the line between `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` with the lines defined by `x=0`, `y=0`, `x=w`, `y=h` (where `w` and `h` are the width and height of the window.

The easiest way to do this is by using homogeneous coordinates, representing the points and lines as 3-vectors. You can conveniently model these using the [`Point3D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html) class.

The main advantage of homogeneous coordinates is it handles all "slants" identically: for example, you could use 2D coordinates, i.e. work out the equation of the slanted line in the form `y = mx + c`, rearrange to find the intersection points etc; but this doesn't work for a vertical line (where m is infinite). You can work around it, but it gets a bit messy, and is numerically less-well conditioned.

---

In homogeneous coordinates, you represent a line `ax + by + c = 0` as the vector `[a b c]'`.

You can calculate the intersection point of two lines via the cross product of two vectors representing lines:

```
[ a1 ]   [ a2 ]    [   b1 * c2 - c1 * b2 ]
[ b1 ] x [ b2 ]  = [ - a1 * c2 + c1 * a2 ]
[ c1 ]   [ c2 ]    [   a1 * b2 - b1 * a2 ]
```

Consider that a point `(X, Y)` is at the intersection of lines `x = X` and `y = Y`; so, by the above formula, the homogeneous coordinate of `(X, Y)` is:

```
[ 1  ]   [ 0  ]   [ X ]
[ 0  ] x [ 1  ] = [ Y ]
[ -X ]   [ -Y ]   [ 1 ]
```

Also, the line between two points in homogeneous notation is given by the cross-product of the two points

```
[ x1 ]   [ x2 ]   [ y1 - y2       ]
[ y1 ] x [ y2 ] = [ -x1 + x2      ]
[  1 ]   [  1 ]   [ x1*y2 - x2*y1 ]
```

(Don't worry about all these fiddly expressions: they are very easy to make a typo in, and I'm sure I have; but you don't have to implement them manually because methods exist in the `Point3D` class).

The other important thing to note is that you can scale homogeneous coordinates without changing the point or line.

For example, `[ka  kb  kc]` is exactly the same as `[a b c]`: all the coordinates have been multiplied by the same factor, `k`. This leaves the point/line completely unchanged.

---

So, we can represent the slanted line as a `Point3D`:

```
Point3D p1 = new Point3D(x1, y1, 1);
Point3D p2 = new Point3D(x2, y2, 1);
Point3D slantedLine = p1.crossProduct(p2);
```

We can represent the four edges of the viewport with equations `x=0`, `x=w`, `y=0`, `y=h`:

```
Point3D lineX_equals_0 = new Point3D(1, 0, 0);
Point3D lineX_equals_w = new Point3D(1, 0, -w);
Point3D lineY_equals_0 = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
Point3D lineY_equals_h = new Point3D(0, 1, -h);
```

and we can find the intersections of these lines with the slanted line:

```
Point3D intersectionX_equals_0 = slantedLine.crossProduct(lineX_equals_0);
Point3D intersectionX_equals_w = slantedLine.crossProduct(lineX_equals_w);
Point3D intersectionY_equals_0 = slantedLine.crossProduct(lineY_equals_0);
Point3D intersectionY_equals_h = slantedLine.crossProduct(lineY_equals_h);
```

So, now you have 4 homogeneous points where the slanted line intersects the respective edges. In order to extend your slanted line to meet these, you need to convert them back to things you can interpret as 2D coordinates.

Remember that a 2d point `(x, y)` is represented as the 3d point `(x, y, 1)`: we can convert the insection points by dividing them by their z component:

```
intersectionX_equals_0 = intersectionX_equals_0.multiply(1 / intersectionX_equals_0.getZ());
intersectionX_equals_w = intersectionX_equals_w.multiply(1 / intersectionX_equals_w.getZ());

intersectionY_equals_0 = intersectionY_equals_0.multiply(1 / intersectionY_equals_0.getZ());
intersectionY_equals_h = intersectionY_equals_h.multiply(1 / intersectionY_equals_h.getZ());
```

Now, work out which of those points sit within the drawable portion of the window: a point is drawable if `0 <= x <= w`, and `0 <= y <= h`.

You can pick 2 drawable points, and draw your line between them.

Let's put all of this together:

```
Point3D p1 = new Point3D(x1, y1, 1);
Point3D p2 = new Point3D(x2, y2, 1);
Point3D slantedLine = p1.crossProduct(p2);

Set<Point2D> intersectionPoints =
    Stream.of(
        new Point3D(1, 0, 0),
        new Point3D(1, 0, -w),
        new Point3D(0, 1, 0),
        new Point3D(0, 1, -h))
      .map(slantedLine::crossProduct)
      .filter(p -> p.getZ() != 0)  // Remove edges parallel to slanted line
      .map(p -> p.multiply(1 / p.getZ()))
      .filter(p -> p.getX() >= 0 && p.getX() <= w)
      .filter(p -> p.getY() >= 0 && p.getY() <= h)
      .map(p -> new Point2D(p.getX(), p.getY()))
      .collect(toSet());
```

That gives you the points:

- if there are two points, just draw the line between those two points
- if there are three points, the line intersects the viewport at one corner
- if there are four points, the line intersects the viewport at two corners
- if there are fewer than two points, the problem is degenerate (e.g. w or h is 0, or x1=x2 and y1=y2)

You will need to consider how to handle the not-two-point cases.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and for sharing your time and knowledge.

Comment: @Tretonis, if this answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it as correct.